# Pushing Data from UITableViewCell to ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, segue

I am trying to push data from a UITableViewCell into another view controller. I have tried two separate ways, `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` and also `PrepareForSegue`. In both instances the ViewController loads correctly but the data is not being passed across (either null, or the first array value).

Here is my instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier method, when I log the variable within my ViewController it just returns null.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *testNumber = [jobNumberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"Job is... %@",testNumber);
StandardInfoViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StandardInfoViewController"];
controller.JobNr = [jobNumberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Prepare For Segue

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Details" sender: self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Details"]){
    StandardInfoViewController *controller = (StandardInfoViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    controller.jobNumber = [jobNumberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
}
```

When I use the prepareForSegue call I get the first row of my Array, which I understand because it doesn't know the cell, but I don't know how to identify the Cell within the prepareForSegue call.

I hope this makes sense, and any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: how is `JobNr` declared?

Comment: JobNr is declared as a NSString within my ViewController.h

Comment: Well, that is obvious. but how?

Comment: Apologies. @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *JobNr;

Comment: NSString should be always declared as `copy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you drag the segue FROM the tableView-cell in the storyboard, you will then get the cell itself as parameter sender.

then you can use `tableView indexPathForCell:sender` to get the actual index of the selected cell. Then just fetch your object normally.

I.e. you will **not** need to implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

---

If you still want to use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, just pass the cell as the sender parameter manually. I.e:

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Details" 
                      sender:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]]
```

---

Although your first version with `instansiateViewController` should work, judging by your code.

---

Another pattern is to subclass the cells themselves, and let them have a property that is the object that they want to display. Then you can just fetch the object directly from the cell without calling the data-array itself.

Comment: Thank you very much! It took me a while, because I was changing the code all over and losing track of what I had done but the 'tableView indexPathForCell:sender' worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

This is how you identify Cell in prepareForSegue method.

```
    **UITableViewCell *cell=[myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];**

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Details"]){
    StandardInfoViewController *controller = (StandardInfoViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    **UITableViewCell *cell=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];**
    controller.jobNumber = [jobNumberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
}
```